# For loop in R and apply alternative

Tags: r, validation

I'm trying to use a validation approach to determine the test error of a model for several different training samples.

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train1 <- sample(10000,5000)
train2 <- sample(10000,5000)
train3 <- sample(10000,5000)
trains <- c('train1','train2','train3')
verror = rep(0,3)
for (i in trains){
  glm.fit <- glm(default~income+balance,data=Default,family='binomial',subset=i)
  logitpred <- predict(glm.fit,Default[-i,],type='response')
  classifier <- rep('No',length(logitpred))
  classifier[logitpred > 0.5] <- 'Yes'
  verror[i] <- 1-mean(Default[-i,]$default==classifier)
}
```

I get an "Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : 
  variable 1 has no levels" error with my 'for' loop, but I can't figure out why.  Also, is there an easy way to implement this with an apply function?

Comment: In case anyone runs into this error for a completely different reason, and you're using `stats::glm`, try using `lme4::glmer` instead. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `i` which is a string rather than a vector or a number

Try instead something like

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train1 <- sample(10000,5000)
train2 <- sample(10000,5000)
train3 <- sample(10000,5000)
trains <- data.frame(train1,train2,train3)                           ## changed
verror = numeric()                                                   ## changed
for (i in trains){
  glm.fit <- glm(default~income+balance,data=Default,family='binomial',subset=i)
  logitpred <- predict(glm.fit,Default[-i,],type='response')
  classifier <- rep('No',length(logitpred))
  classifier[logitpred > 0.5] <- 'Yes'
  verror <- c(verror, 1-mean(Default[-i,]$default==classifier))      ## changed
}
```

or using `sapply`

```
verrorcalc <- function(i){
  glm.fit <- glm(default~income+balance,data=Default,family='binomial',subset=i)
  logitpred <- predict(glm.fit,Default[-i,],type='response')
  classifier <- rep('No',length(logitpred))
  classifier[logitpred > 0.5] <- 'Yes'
  1-mean(Default[-i,]$default==classifier)
}
verror_alt <- sapply(trains, verrorcalc)
```

to give

```
> verror 
[1] 0.0286 0.0236 0.0280
> verror_alt
train1 train2 train3 
0.0286 0.0236 0.0280
```